# Passing VBA execution to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I though there would be many answers to this question, but didn't find any obvious one.

Is it possible to pass VBA execution to another workbook ?

What I'd like to do is : pass execution from `ThisWorbook` (WbA) to another workbook (WbB, ie make WbB the new `ThisWorkook`), then close Wb A.

### Edit

**What I'm actually trying to do...**

I'm looking for a way to update a workbook I'm distributing to a few people and which contains 20 sheets + 10 code modules + 10 userforms.

**My current solution**

Every time the workbook (WbA) is open, the code will first check if a newer version is available on a network directory. If so, the macro propose to the user to automatically download/save the new workbook (WbB) and export user data from WbA.

But, after that, I'm forced to tell the user it can now closed WbA and open WbB and import the data back in WbB.

I'd rather automate the close WbA / open WbB / import data back too.

Comment: Yes, call the second macro and pass the workbook(s) through to that macro, then you should be able to "reset" the variables and go from there.

Comment: If you close the Workbook that originated the code call the code itself will close. AFAIK there is no way to pass execution to another workbook and then be able to close the originating workbook.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but you could put the VBA you are running in your personal macro workbook.  Then you can run it without the code being dependent on a specific workbook.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Ah yeah, I was just starting to write a way to do what I meant, and realized that when I close the workbook with the macro, of course the macro stops! :P

Comment: Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you want to close the workbook and continue the same macro? Couldn't you write the first half of the macro, then call a second macro that picks up after the first?  Or, just hide the first workbook until the single macro is done, and *then* close it?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - That what I though (pass execution is not possible). But I was surprised not to find such a question here.

Comment: @BruceWayne - I updated the question to add what I'm trying to do. Hiding such a big workbook is not an option and would left me with the same problem next time.

Comment: "...tell the user it can now close WbA and open WB and import the data back." - do you mean import the data back to WbA? ...Hm, what if you instead ran this from Personal.xlsb and went from there? Instead of storing this in WbA.  Or am I correct in Assuming you can't simply add this to people's Personal.xlsbs.  ...maybe run it from an Add-on?

Comment: @BruceWayne that. This is an application-level problem in need of an application-level solution. A nicely written Excel add-in could handle this much better.

Comment: @BruceWayne - No, opening WbB then importing user data in WbB. - I'm not willing to use Personal.xlsb (and putting it in XLSTART...) since I don't want this big Wb to load everytime a user launch Excel (but only when needed) and since I'm not willing to modify user's Personal.xlsb. And regarding my problem of updating the macro, having it in XLSTART would probably make it more difficult. Regarding Add-On, I don't know much about that but wouldn't updating the Add-On be complicated too ?

Comment: You write it so that it *doesn't* need to be updated to handle a new version of WbA/WbB.

Comment: The best idea is, as @Mat'sMug says, to use an add-in for the macros (and probably load those macros all the time), but I would keep the data in a separate workbook/s and only open it/them when it/they need to be used.  (i.e. the `xlam` should only contain the code and, perhaps, sheets containing lookup tables used to simplify coding - but any data, or anything the user can change / configure, would be in the data workbooks.)  And if the macros are updated to handle a new format of the data workbook, include code that automatically updates old format workbooks.

Comment: I should clearly separate `code` vs `user data & parameters` (and make it a real VB application). Actually, the macro do uses a `parameters folder` (C:/Temp/myMacro since it doesn't need any folder permission), for debug logging, error logging, temporary user data, downloads... It also make use of a read only `network folder` for updating lookup tables and databases... Having the code in a `xlam Add-In` would make sense considering the `application-level` vs `Wb-level` discussion, but if the `Add-In` contains all the code, wouldn't that make it more difficult to update the code and userfoms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `Application.OnTime`:

Code in WbA.xlsm:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.OnTime Now(), "WbB.xlsm!Macro2"
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Code in WbB.xlsm:

```
Sub Macro2()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name & " says hello"
End Sub
```

Because `Macro2` is being called by the Application via a scheduled task, it no longer needs WbA to be open.

---

Note:  `WbB.xlsm` does not even need to be open when `Macro1` is run, providing you fully qualify the workbook name:

Code in WbA.xlsm:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.OnTime Now(), "'C:\Temp\SO_Test\WbB.xlsm'!Macro2"
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Code in WbB.xlsm:

```
Sub Macro2()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name & " says hello"
End Sub
```

Assuming `WbA.xlsm` was the only workbook open in Excel when `Macro1` was run, you might actually see an empty Excel for a very short time before `WbB.xlsm` is opened and execution continues.

Comment: Ok, I'm forced to upvote this. But I **have** to say this kind of circular-referencing code is completely disgusting and I would be **very** mad at whoever used this trick in production code. That hack defies the VBA call stack logic, defies common sense, defies everything that's good in the world.

Comment: @Mat'sMug You should know by now that I have no logic (even if VBA does have call stack logic), that I have no common sense, and that I (and everything else in the world) can't be called "good". :D

Comment: @OP FWIW the *real* reason I dislike this solution is because `WbB.xlsm` has no business knowing about `WbA.xlsm` - the Golden Rule is that the object that creates something, is responsible for destroying that thing. So if A creates B, then B can't destroy A - it's A's responsibility to destroy B, by any programming standards.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Edited answer so that `WbB.xlsm` knows nothing about `WbA.xlsm`.  (It's actually how I originally tested it, but I decided to move the close into `WbB.xlsm` just to ensure that it worked there too, and that's how it was when I pasted the code into the answer.)

Comment: That's **much** better!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Simplified it even more.  (I wasn't sure whether `OnTime` would handle a call to another workbook, but it does.)

Comment: ...Wow, this is neat/crazy.  And also, I think I [found a picture of you](https://i.imgur.com/2Qgxpp4.png) writing this answer.

Comment: @BruceWayne People in my office are going to wonder what I am laughing about.  They might actually work out that I'm not doing what I am being paid to do - so stop posting those pics! :D

Comment: I had a self updating sheet a while ago, upon open it would look for an open workbook with the same name and _old at the end and close it without save (this is incase it had just self updated). Then it would check for a new version, if it existed then it would rename itself to have _old at the end which didn't stop any code running, it would then copy the new one then the last thing the auto_open macro did was open the new one.

Comment: @YowE3K - Forget to mention I'd also need to pass some args to WbB (the location (WbC) of user data exported from WbA that need to be imported back in WbB). I don't think OnTime would let me do that (but I could export the location into some config file or stored those data in a know location)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - About to golden rule. Actually, next step would actually be WbB killing (ie destroying) WbA since WbB would become the new WbA (if that make any sense, see my edit about what I'm trying to do)

Comment: @Tibo Ah, I see now. You see a macro is meant to operate at workbook level, and IMO the problem you're solving is at application level - I'll try to spare a minute to write up a more idiomatic solution tonight.

Comment: @Mat'sMug. This should totally be an application rather than a wb. We actually asked our external dev team if they could include an equivalent of my 'macro' in our Information System, but due to time constraint (+ an expected life time of the 'macro' of less than 10 months), I'm stuck with do what I can with Excel. I'm not sure of what an "idiomatic solution" means and looks like. Please, let me understand what that means before writing any code. (Another constraint is I need to be able to understand/update... the whole solution).

Comment: @Tibo very simple: make it an Excel add-in; it loads with Excel, and closes with Excel. I have ideas about how to deal with the versioning so that you don't need to redeploy the add-in every time a new version is issued, but essentially, move the app-level code to its own workbook and then Save As "Excel Add-in" - and then you can have fancypants buttons in the Ribbon to run your add-in code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug. The macro being rather big (20 sheets + 10 code modules + 10 userforms), I don't it to be launched with Excel but only when the user need it. To do so, maybe I could include in the Add-In only the fraction of the code needed to check if a new version of the macro in available on the network... But then I'm stuck with how to update the Add-In. (One reason to deploy the update could be that the network directory is expected to change in the next few days). I do use a personal xlam Add-In and Ribbon but I'm not sure if Add-In is easy to deal with when distributing it...

Comment: Huh, I used to run and distribute an Excel add-in with over 70 class modules. Not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: The Wb take about 6Mo, have about 150 Public Const, load big 2D arrays in memory, have 20 sheets with formatting... so I'd rather not have it loaded unless when necessary. (Note there aren't any class module since I have know idea about what it is used for...)

Answer (score -3):

You just have to leave workbook A open while the code runs, the last line of code you need to execute should be

```
WorkbookA.Close
```

Comment: That doesn't fit my problem. I'm trying to pass execution and kill WbA, not just halt execution for a while...